# How to send complete object as message from producer to consumer in php rabbitmq

Tags: php, rabbitmq

How to send complete object having some private properties as message from producer to consumer in php rabbitmq

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the object to a text based data structure, typically a JSON object. Something like [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) would be a good place to start

Answer (score 1):

It's better to have a function inside the object which returns the particular properties which you need to send a message to json_encode

For Example

```
class Cycle{
    private $name;
    private $notSending;
    public $type;

    public function getProducerMessage(){
        return json_encode( [ 'name' => $this->name, 'type' => $this->type ] );
    }
}
```